# What HTTP headers are presented in a cross domain call?

Tags: javascript, csrf, same-origin-policy, antiforgerytoken

I'm trying to [prevent a CSRF attack](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/203173/396) when a single API is used by both Javascript and native clients.

I could resolve this with custom logic within the AntiXSS filter if I can depend on Javascript to consistently set or omit certain HTTP headers.

Are there any HTTP headers that aren't directly accessible by Javascript, but are set by the browser that a server could rely upon to distinguish between a native client vs a Javascript client?

Comment: What if JS supports them in the future? Wouldn't it be risky?

Comment: CORS lets you define a set of allowed headers for cross-origin requests, specified in the `access-control-allowed-headers` header.

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense  what is the preferred way for a server api to determine if Javascript specific security checks are needed? Implementors of native clients prefer to not maintain cookies when calling an API, regardless of its GET or (potentially CSRF vulnerable) POST

Comment: The Origin request header is set by the browser for all scripted cross-origin requests, and isn’t settable from frontend JavaScript. For CORS preflight OPTIONS requests, the Access-Control-Request-Headers and Access-Control-Request-Method request headers are set by browsers, and are not settable from frontend JavaScript. There are some other not-settable-from-frontend-JavaScript request headers which are sometimes sent by browsers in particular cases; the complete list is at https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name (the Fetch spec calls them “forbidden header names”)